# i want to know the meaning of "going nuts"

Tags: vocabulary

What's the meaning of "going nuts"?

Could any one of you please explain me this?

Could you please give some examples along with meaning explanation?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20nuts a search is very easy...

Comment: @Zebrafish - While I agree that the results of any dictionary searches should be part of any "What does this mean?" question, in this case, the search might not have been so easy. OneLook only returns [a few hits](https://onelook.com/?w=go+nuts&ls=a) for _go nuts_, and only an Urban Dictionary hit for [_going nuts_](https://onelook.com/?w=going+nuts&ls=a), as compared to [almost 30 hits](https://onelook.com/?w=nuts&ls=a) for _nuts_. That said, most (if not all) of those 30 hits for _nuts_ would at least steer [ell.se] toward the right answer.

Comment: @J.R. I didn't mean to reprove the OP at all. I typed the words "go nuts definition" and it was the very first result in the list. Typing "go nuts" would be less helpful without "definition". My search engine was set to Bing but I just tried Google and got the same thing, all results on the first page being dictionary definitions. Again it was intended as a friendly and constructive piece of advice.

Comment: @Zebrafish - I wasn't saying that you were reproving; I agree that your comment was helpful and constructive. I was merely reacting to how you said that a search "is very easy." Some definitions are trickier to find in dictionaries than others, and I can see how this one might have been tricky, depending on which terms were used, and whether or not the OP tried a search engine or a dictionary.

Comment: @J.R.  - When Googling for a phrase, place the phrase in quotes.  Type `google "go nuts"`.

Comment: @HotLicks - I guess my point isn't getting across? I was merely trying to empathize with the OP. I didn't have any problem finding a meaning online, but not every new user knows all the tricks of the trade.

Comment: @J.R. - Then they need to learn the tricks of the trade.

Comment: @HotLicks - Agreed; that's why I included four links in my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Going nuts' is an idiomatic expression meaning 'going crazy', 'becoming insane', 'manifesting signs of mental illness', etc. In slang a person's head is sometimes called their 'nut'. A patient in a mental hospital is sometimes cruelly called a 'nut case' or just a 'nut'. Often becoming very angry will be called 'going nuts' because a very angry person may resemble a mad person in manner and appearance.